# Android ImageButton not aligned with EditText and Button

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

I currently have this in my layout.xml

```
        <EditText android:id="@+id/body" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Type to compose" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/attach"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/attach_photo" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/send" android:text="@string/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Problem I'm facing is the top of the ImageButton is not aligned like the Button and EditText. The other 2 fill up the height nicely but the ImageButton seems to be sticking out upwards. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding padding doesn't make the button budge either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `RelativeLayout`. You can align views to the sides, top and bottom of the parent or any other `view`.

Using `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` or similar.

There are loads of xml commands you can use in `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the layout weight property on the children of your linear layout. You can set the weight of edittext, imagebutton and button which will align your components on screen.

Comment: This only affects the widget size and not alignment.